# Rotating an image to follow mouse position - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make an image rotate to follow the mouse position just like the ship from asteroids but to be controled with the mouse position instead of the arrow keys... help would be apreciated!

Comment: cool idea, but what do you have so far?

Comment: Check out the `RotateTransform` class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mikus not much, i have basic path finding for incoming enemies but it's too basic more like if distance>1 enemy aproxes 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the position of your image.  You can then find the cursor position by the `MouseMove` event.  This event invokes every time your mouse moves.  You can use the `GetPosition` method to find a `Point` to obtain your `X` and `Y` coordinates.

```
 private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(null);           
    }
```

Now that you've obtained the `X` and `Y` coordinate you can use [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to find the distance between your image and where your cursor is.  Now to find the angle you can `AngleOfImage = sin^-1(Y/total distance between your image and cursor)` to find the angle.

If you want the image to move after it has already rendered you need to use the `RenderTransform` property.  Since you need the image to rotate you can make use of the `RotateTransform` class to accomplish this.  Since you have calculated the angle and set it equal to a property, `AngleOfImage`, you can bind that property to the `Angle` dependency property of `RotateTransform`  So your xaml would look something like this.

```
<Image>
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding AngleOfImage}"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
```

Actual working code for `MouseMove` event to calculate the angle

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var somePoint = e.GetPosition(mainWindow);
        X = somePoint.X;
        Y = somePoint.Y;

        var newX = Abs(X - RectangleOriginX);
        var newY = Abs(Y - RectangleOriginY);
        var powX = Pow(newX, 2);
        var powY = Pow(newY, 2);
        var distance = Sqrt(powX + powY);
        var result = newX / distance;          

        Angle = Asin(result).ToDegrees();
    }
```

Where `ToDegrees()` is just an extension method to convert the value to degrees. `RectangleOriginX` and `RectangleOriginY` are the points of my control I am moving which I got from this

```
 private void mainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var origialPoint = rect.TransformToAncestor(mainWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        RectangleOriginX = origialPoint.X;
        RectangleOriginY = origialPoint.Y;
    }
```

Also my working `xaml`

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="Red">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
```

Comment: `
        private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
            double Distance;
            Distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X,2)+Math.Pow(point.Y,2));
            double AngleOfImage;
            AngleOfImage = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(-1),point.Y/Distance);
        }`

Comment: Don't you need `Distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X-original_X_Distance,2)+Math.Pow(point.Y-original_Y_Distance,2));`  Also, when you do the Asin it will give you the result in radians.  Are you converting back to degrees? The `RotateTransform` `Angle` property has units of degrees

Comment: private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
            double Distance;
            Distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point.X - original_X_Distance, 2) + Math.Pow(point.Y - original_Y_Di‌​stance, 2)); ;
            double angulo = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(-1), point.Y / Distance);
            angulo = angulo * (180.0 / Math.PI);
        }

Comment: Nothing... tryed all night... i think i am doing the binding wrong to the xaml maybe... i dunno anymore

Comment: I got it working with my control.  I edited my post with all the working code.

Comment: still nothing... is that c#?

Comment: yes its c#. Is your `datacontext` set?  If you bind `Angle` with a `textbox` can you see the angle with you move your mouse?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for my bad english

Try to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, and in the `Timer_tick` event call some `Move(MouseEventArgs e)`.

Something like this

```
private void Move(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
     if(mainwindow has focus)
     {
       your_image.Position = NextPosition(e);
     }
    }
```

instance of `MouseEventArgs` is field of your class, which changes in MouseMove event.

In NextPosition you can use any pathfind algorithm

Answer (score -1):

If I can understand you right

you can make it by some maths

- Get the center point first
- Get the mouse position
- Use `Math.ASin()` to get the angle
- It will be like that `Math.ASin(x / d);`

x will be mouse location - image center location

d will be the distance between the center of the image and mouse location you can get it by [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

then use a timer to make that happen.

I hope that my answer will help you.